# .net Update a dictionary while other thread gets a value

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, asp.net-web-api, thread-safety

I have a web project (web API) where speed is the main concern.
each request gets a response (according to some Key) from an in-memory dictionary.

On some other event- this dictionary needs to be updated with new values.
the all process of update take about 20 seconds, and in this time I don't mind to get responses according to dictionary value before the change.

I want to implement the dictionary change, as fast as possible where every Millisecond counts.

I would like to avoid any locks/mutex implementaions as checking their value will also be time consuming.

If there a best practice here? I don't mind "wasting" some calls with old value. Main concern is overall call speed.

What will happen if while:

```
_myDictionary = new Dictionary<>({some dict values});
```

There is a call to get a value from _myDictionary. ?

```
_myDictionary.TryGetValue("some key");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a reference type is guaranteed to be an atomic operation:

> ### 5.5 Atomicity of variable references
>
> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and **reference types**. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list are also atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic. Aside from the library functions designed for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or decrement.

(from the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278(v=vs.71).aspx))

So, preparing a new dictionary and then assigning it when it's all done is perfectly safe.

Comment: I know ConcurrentDictionary, but all get also uses some lock (Thread.MemoryBarrier();) which for me is time wasting, moreover, According to MSN should be used in many read many update scenario, I am talking about many reads, few updates.

Comment: @briler How many elements, reads and writes are we talking here?

Comment: There are many reads, as much as IIS can take a second. writes about once every hour. but As I wrote, I don't mind having the write copy and replacae the all Dictionary entirely, and having the read use old dictionary, just lookign for the way to replace the pointer without causing exceptions, Dictionary size should be in whereabout of 1000-5000 elements

Comment: There we go. Though I really don't think some locking will be noticeable against the time it takes to process an entire IIS request.

Comment: monitor does takes about 20 Nano Second. but I will need a mutex here, this will be 1 ms on timing.